# Vectorize multiplying RGB array by color transform matrix, for image processing

Tags: python, image, numpy, vectorization, rgb

I'm teaching myself about color image processing using Python 3 (NumPy for this particular task).

I have a 3d array `image` representing the RGB values at each pixel of the image so its shape is (height,width,3). At every pixel, I want to make new RGB values which are some linear combination of the original RGB values at that given pixel. I will do this by multiplying the RGB vector at each pixel by `W`, a 3x3 matrix of weights.

I could accomplish this with nested for loops, but it's slow:

```
newRGB = np.zeros((height,width,3))   # make empty array to update with RGB values
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):                     
        RGB = image[i,j,:]            # RGB vector at given pixel with size 3 since is [R,G,B]
        new = np.dot(W,RGB)           # W is 3x3 matrix of weights
        newRGB[i,j,:] = new           # put new RGB values into the empty matrix
```

Alternatively, a faster vectorized way is:

```
image = mpimg.imread('test.png')   # reading image file into matplotlib.image
print(image.shape)                 # image has shape (height,width,3)
W = np.array([...])                # arbitrary 3x3 matrix of weights  
x = np.rollaxis(image,2,1)         # moving the RGB axis to 2nd position
print(x.shape)                     # x has shape (height,3,width)
Wx = np.dot(W,x)                   # matrix multiplication
print(Wx.shape)                    # Wx has shape (3,height,width)
y = np.rollaxis(Wx,0,3)            # moving RGB axis back to 3rd position to have image shape
print(y.shape)                     # y has shape (height,width,3) like original image
```

Is there a less cumbersome way of doing this, e.g. by using numpy.tensordot()?

Alternatively, since I'm taking linear combinations of RGB values, could I create some kind of 3D linear filter and convolve it with my image by doing simple elementwise multiplications in FFT space?

Right now my images are about 1000x1000 pixels, so the RGB array shape is roughly (1000,1000,3). But I'm also interested in vectorization for other applications which could have much bigger arrays (or also higher dimensions), so answers relevant to bigger array sizes and dimensions are also appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't call it *"3d tensor representing the RGB values"*, I'd just say *RGB array (/ RGBa array)*. It's essentially a set of 3(/4) 2D arrays; the third dimension is always understood to just be RGB/RGBa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could use [np.tensordot](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) or [np.einsum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
In [9]: np.tensordot(image, W, ([2], [1])).shape
Out[9]: (1000, 1000, 3)

In [13]: np.einsum('ijk,lk->ijl', image, W).shape
Out[13]: (1000, 1000, 3)


In [19]: x = np.rollaxis(image,2,1)

In [20]: Wx = np.dot(W,x)

In [21]: y = np.rollaxis(Wx,0,3)

In [22]: np.allclose(np.tensordot(image, W, ([2], [1])), y)
Out[22]: True

In [14]: np.allclose(np.tensordot(image, W, ([2], [1])), np.einsum('ijk,lk->ijl', image, W))
Out[14]: True
```

of the two, np.tensordot appears to be the faster method in this case.

```
In [15]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,lk->ijl', image, W)
10 loops, best of 3: 31.1 ms per loop

In [16]: %timeit np.tensordot(image, W, ([2], [1]))
100 loops, best of 3: 18.9 ms per loop
```